# Rbind, having data frames within data frames causes errors?

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have a data.frame which in turn contains data.frames, now using rbind on two identical sets (e.g `rbind(k,k)`) of this data throws the error:

> Error in xpdrows.data.frame(x, rows, new.rows) :    number of items to
>   replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Below is the structure of the object with the data.

```
> str(k)
'data.frame':   25 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ location         :'data.frame':  25 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ address   :'data.frame':  25 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ streetAddress: chr  "Astrakangatan 110A" "Västmannagatan 85C" "Doktor Abelins gata 6" "Standarvägen 1" ...
  ..$ position  :'data.frame':  25 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ latitude : num  59.4 59.3 59.3 59.3 59.3 ...
  .. ..$ longitude: num  17.8 18 18.1 18 18 ...
  ..$ namedAreas:List of 25
  .. ..$ : chr "Hässelby"
  .. ..$ : chr "Vasastan"
  .. ..$ : chr "Södermalm"
  .. ..$ : chr "Gamla Älvsjö"
  .. ..$ : chr "Fruängen-Hägersten"
  .. ..$ : chr "Södermalm"
  .. ..$ : chr "Kungsholmen"
  .. ..$ : chr "Fruängen"
  .. ..$ : chr "Årsta"
  .. ..$ : chr "Telefonplan"
  .. ..$ : chr "Kista"
  .. ..$ : chr "Östberga"
  .. ..$ : chr "Hägerstensåsen"
  .. ..$ : chr "Östermalm"
  .. ..$ : chr "Årsta"
  .. ..$ : chr "Bromma Blackeberg"
  .. ..$ : chr "Similar Listings Overwritten Here"
  .. ..$ : chr "Traneberg"
  .. ..$ : chr "Kungsholmen"
  .. ..$ : chr "Skärholmen"
  .. ..$ : chr "Katarina"
  .. ..$ : chr "Farsta stadsdelsområde"
  .. ..$ : chr "Kista"
  .. ..$ : chr "Bromma"
  .. ..$ : chr "Akalla"
  ..$ region    :'data.frame':  25 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ municipalityName: chr  "Stockholm" "Stockholm" "Stockholm" "Stockholm" ...
  .. ..$ countyName      : chr  "Stockholms län" "Stockholms län" "Stockholms län" "Stockholms län" ...
  ..$ distance  :'data.frame':  25 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ ocean: int  NA 2325 1223 6360 NA 329 2630 NA 2837 5537 ...
 $ listPrice        : int  1900000 4100000 4875000 2950000 1995000 1395000 2450000 2250000 2550000 1995000 ...
 $ rent             : int  4678 1586 3092 3983 2587 520 1437 3644 2936 2707 ...
 $ floor            : num  1 1 NA 1 3 0.5 1 6 3 NA ...
 $ livingArea       : num  60 40 70 91 37 11 28 59 54 42 ...
 $ source           :'data.frame':  25 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ name: chr  "HusmanHagberg" "BOSTHLM" "Gripsholms Fastighetsförmedling" "Fastighetsbyrån" ...
  ..$ id  : int  1610 1499 9895524 1573 58 713 2091 1566 1566 1566 ...
  ..$ type: chr  "Broker" "Broker" "Broker" "Broker" ...
  ..$ url : chr  "http://www.husmanhagberg.se/" "http://www.bosthlm.se/" "http://gripsholms.se/" "http://www.fastighetsbyran.se/" ...
 $ rooms            : num  2 2 2.5 3.5 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ published        : Date, format: "2015-07-17" "2015-07-16" "2015-07-15" "2015-07-10" ...
 $ constructionYear : int  2006 NA 1929 1937 NA 1929 1930 2014 1949 1944 ...
 $ objectType       : chr  "Lägenhet" "Lägenhet" "Lägenhet" "Lägenhet" ...
 $ booliId          : int  1920703 1919949 1896584 1917520 1918145 1918049 1917638 1849399 1916805 1826479 ...
 $ soldDate         : Date, format: "2015-07-21" "2015-07-19" "2015-07-20" "2015-07-20" ...
 $ soldPrice        : int  2000000 4100000 5175000 4200000 2500000 1850000 2820000 2600000 2900000 2230000 ...
 $ url              : chr  "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/hasselby/astrakangatan+110a/1920703" "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/vasastan/vastmannagatan+85c/1919949" "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/sodermalm/doktor+abelins+gata+6/1896584" "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/gamla+alvsjo/standarvagen+1/1917520" ...
 $ isNewConstruction: int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ plotArea         : int  NA NA NA NA 0 NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ AreaSize         : Factor w/ 10 levels "10","20","30",..: 6 4 7 9 3 1 2 5 5 4 ...
 $ PriceDiff        : int  100000 0 300000 1250000 505000 455000 370000 350000 350000 235000 ...
```

Is using data frames within data frames ill advised? Or have I made a mistake?

@SimonG, Answer is great. But I'm stumbling upon a non-unique row-names error. Now using the `nrbind()`works fine for individual columns or data frames, `e.g. mapply(nrbind, k$location, k$location)` but somehow doesn't run when running the whole data.frame. Even if I change the rownames with `row.names` it still throws the error.

```
> nrbind <- function(x,y) if(is.data.frame(x)) rbind(x,y) else c(x,y)
> as.data.frame( mapply(nrbind, k, k) )
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘1’, ‘10’, ‘11’, ‘12’, ‘13’, ‘14’, ‘15’, ‘16’, ‘17’, ‘18’, ‘19’, ‘2’, ‘20’, ‘21’, ‘22’, ‘23’, ‘24’, ‘25’, ‘3’, ‘4’, ‘5’, ‘6’, ‘7’, ‘8’, ‘9’
```

Comment: I only just saw that your data frame contains multiple levels of nesting. I have updated my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

It took me a while to actually produce a "nested" data frame like yours.
Personally, I would avoid nesting data frames like that. This will only be a minor adjustment to your code and enable you to use the standard functions in R (see option 2 below).

However, if you insist on having nested data frames, you can "mimic" the functionality of `rbind` using `mapply`, where a mix of `rbind` and `c` is applied depending on whether the elements of the data frame are data frames themselves. I have written a small example for two data frames (see option 1 below).

**Option 1: single level of nesting**

```
a <- letters[1:5]
xy <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=5:1)

k <- data.frame(a)
k[["xy"]] <- xy

# 'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a : Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ xy:'data.frame':     5 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ x: int  1 2 3 4 5
#   ..$ y: int  5 4 3 2 1

nrbind <- function(x,y) if(is.data.frame(x)) rbind(x,y) else c(x,y)
as.data.frame( mapply(nrbind, k, k) )

#    a xy.x xy.y
# 1  1    1    5
# 2  2    2    4
# 3  3    3    3
# 4  4    4    2
# 5  5    5    1
# 6  1    1    5
# 7  2    2    4
# 8  3    3    3
# 9  4    4    2
# 10 5    5    1
```

Note that the function `nrbind` above is really "quick and dirty". However, adjusting it to suit your needs should be straightforward.

Also note that the result of `mapply` will not be a nested data frame anymore. Therefore, in order to use option 1 repeatedly, you have to extend the function `nrbind` instead of running `mapply` repeatedly.

**Option 2: redefine as regular `data.frame`**

```
k <- data.frame(a=a, xy=xy)

# 'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a   : Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ xy.x: int  1 2 3 4 5
#  $ xy.y: int  5 4 3 2 1

rbind(k, k) # result as above
```

Using a regular data frame would be my preferred way of doing this.

**[EDIT:] Option 3: higher levels of nesting**

Originally, I didn't see that your data frame was actually nested multiple times. The two options above only work for a single level of nesting or no nesting at all.

Multiple levels of nesting can be adressed by making the whole thing recursive.

```
b <- data.frame(a)
b[["z"]] <- data.frame(z1=1:5, z2=5:1)
k <- data.frame(a)
k[["b"]] <- b; k[["xy"]] <- xy

# 'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a : Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ b :'data.frame':     5 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ a: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#   ..$ z:'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ z1: int  1 2 3 4 5
#   .. ..$ z2: int  5 4 3 2 1
#  $ xy:'data.frame':     5 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ x: int  1 2 3 4 5
#   ..$ y: int  5 4 3 2 1

recursive.rbind <- function(x,y){
  ll <- lapply(seq_along(x), function(i){ 
    if(is.data.frame(x[[i]])) nrbind(x[[i]],y[[i]]) else rbind(x[i],y[i])
  })
  names(ll) <- names(x)
  as.data.frame(ll)
}

recursive.rbind(k,k)

#    a b.a b.z.z1 b.z.z2 xy.x xy.y
# 1  a   a      1      5    1    5
# 2  b   b      2      4    2    4
# 3  c   c      3      3    3    3
# 4  d   d      4      2    4    2
# 5  e   e      5      1    5    1
# 6  a   a      1      5    1    5
# 7  b   b      2      4    2    4
# 8  c   c      3      3    3    3
# 9  d   d      4      2    4    2
# 10 e   e      5      1    5    1
```

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem (unless of course someone gives a better one!) :)

Comment: One small issue that has arised ;) When using your option two with mapply. I get an non-unique row name error. Now my rownames will all be same. Do you know any direct solutions to this? This happened also when clearing the row names before running the code ( row.names(k) <- NULL)

Comment: Are you sure? In the example above, option 1 works with `mapply`, and option 2 works with both `mapply` and `rbind`. I only receive an error when using option 1 with `rbind` (with the error message you describe). Are you sure you have the "correct" `k`?

Comment: Yepp I'm using the correct k. I'm getting a little confused here. In Option 2, what would the equivalent of using the real k for section "k <- data.frame(a=a, xy=xy)" be? Should I replace a and xy with the dataframes and other vectors within the real k?

Comment: If you're starting with a nested data frame `k`, then you can convert it to a regular data frame using `as.data.frame(as.list(k))`.

Comment: I still can't get around the unique rownames error. I have edited my question above to incorporate my code and the error output.

Comment: That occurs because your data frame contains multiple levels of nesting. I have only noticed that now. A added a recursive solution in my answer (option 3).